# WSO2 delivery-garantee pattern implementation: doesn't work sampling processor with more than 20 attempts

Tags: wso2

I'm quite a newbie in WSO2 so sorry for the mistakes (and for my english too ... )

I need to implement a proxy with delivery-garantee pattern and here you are my solution (I'm started from this post http://charith.wickramaarachchi.org/2012/05/another-message-redelivery-pattern-with.html):

- a proxy invoke an external service giving, as input, the initial
  client message
- if the external service is running all works fine and
  the reply is given to the client
- if the external service is down or generate a SOAP fault, I'll
  put the message in a store (retry store), and then, using a sampling
  processor (after a time "t"), I'll try again for "n" max attempts:
  at any attempt, if the external service is down or generate a SOAP
  fault, I'll put the message again in the retry store, and the
  process is repeated
- after "n" attempts, if the external service is still out of
  service, the message is stored in another store (garbage store)

All works fine when I try to test with one message, but when I try to test with more messages (> 20 but this number is variable ... ), the sampling processor hangs completely, nothing is shown in the logs. Looking in the console, sometimes (but not always ...), the processor is off, deactivate and in this case, to restore, I need to undeploy, stop and restart, and then deploy again my .car.

NOTE: I've to use the sampling processor and not the forwarding processor because this processor, after "n" attempts deactive itself and I can't use it for my goals.

I can't put here the complete code because is too long, but I can give you a sample .car that you can deploy and execute on your WSO2 installation (to simulate the external service I've used the echo service ...).

[Here you are the sample car that you can download](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mk6g6nve0k2anec/AADPu6Qwk8QWbGBy_u9ZghQva?dl=0)

Thank you very much in advance: all suggestions are appreciated!!!

Cesare

Answer (score 1):

**Message Forwarding Processor**
Retrieves the messages stored in a message store and ***reliably*** forwards them to a specified endpoint. This processor attempts to send one message at a time and ***it does not dequeue a message from the store until it receives a response from the target endpoint***. Therefore this processor is ***ideal for implementing in-order delivery scenarios and guaranteed delivery scenarios***.

**Sampling Processor**
Retrieves the messages stored in a message store and injects them to a given sequence at specified intervals. This processor utilizes the Quartz scheduler framework for periodically processing messages. This can be used to implement message rate throttling scenarios.

--> You can use the forwarding processor and configure it so that it will never be deactivated, just add this parameter : `<parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">-1</parameter>`

Comment: Thank you Jean-Michel for the quickly response. I've tried to use that configuration but seems that does not work properly. In any case there is the problem that I'd like to know that after "n" attempts  I've to stop to send messagges at my external services. In any case I'll try to test forwarding processor again ...

Comment: with max.delivery.attempts=-1, your Message Processor should'nt stop. However, a similar configuration is needed in your endpoint : enter "-1" as a value for Error codes in Avanced options -> Endpoint suspend state and Endpoint timeout state : the xml config should containt  <suspendOnFailure>
         <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>